# How to determine who ran a Spring Batch Job?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm supporting a number of batch jobs and need to see who triggered those manual jobs from the spring batch admin console. I know that users need to be authenticated to manually run jobs but can't see where / if this gets captured?

Comment: by "batch admin console" do you mean Spring Batch Admin?

Comment: I do - question edited

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that out of the box. FYI, Spring Batch Admin is not maintained anymore: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin#note-this-project-is-being-moved-to-the-spring-attic-and-is-not-recommended-for-new-projects--spring-cloud-data-flow-is-the-recommended-replacement-for-managing-and-monitoring-spring-batch-jobs-going-forward--you-can-read-more-about-migrating-to-spring-cloud-data-flow-here